# Using Selenium to get the contents of a DIV that's been filled with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, html, selenium

I'm working with Selenium to automatically load all of the comments of a New York Times article.  Once they are loaded, I want to get the comments and store that information to use later.  However, when looking at the source code for the article I see that the comments DIV is empty, so the NYT is likely using javascript to dynamically fill it with comments in real time.  Since the comments aren't in the source code, I'm unsure how to get the code for the comments as I see it in Firebug.  I *think* that what I want is the DOM, but any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Using Web Driver? You figure out how they are loading it? Does it rely on scroll position?

Comment: Using IDE, but am thinking I may need to switch to Web Driver for these purposes.  Not sure how they're loading it, but my professor thinks it may be with javascript.  Scroll position does not seem to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = document.getElementById('myDivId').innerHTML;
```

This is basically how you can retrieve the html content from HTML element.

Comment: Not going to help with selenium.

Comment: @epascarello: Why not? You can always use Selenium's `getEval` method to execute that piece of javascript on the page.

Comment: And why would use use getEval when it has built in methods to get content?

Comment: @epascarello: Care to elaborate?

Comment: @slebetman: One problem is that not every element explicitly has the 'id' attribute, and I don't know any way to get the browser's internally generated id (if such a thing even exists).  But this might be helpful in certain cases where the 'id' is explicit/known.

Comment: @arya: The browser does not generate an internal id. If an element does not have an id but you know where that element is in the document then you can traverse the document DOM. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference. Specifically, check out the `children` property of DOM elements.